# Suppress NTLM Auth in Java

Tags: java, ntlm, urlconnection

I am currently pen-testing a web application and came across an interesting phenomenon. During my testing sessions, I gathered URLs using a proxy. Now I wanted to test my URL list for anonymous access, so i wrote this little tool

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TrustAllCerts.disableCertChecks();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("urls.txt"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String urlStr = br.readLine();
        while (urlStr != null) {
            if (urlStr.trim().length() > 0) {
                URL url = new URL(urlStr);

                HttpsURLConnection urlc = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    System.out.println(urlStr);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("["+urlc.getResponseCode()+"] "+urlStr);
                }
                urlc.disconnect();
            }
            urlStr = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It does basically nothing, but opening an URL connection on a given URL and test the HTTP response code (actually I implemented some more tests, if I'm getting redirected to a login page). However, the problem is, that this specific application (some custom MS SQL Server Reporting Services) is configured to use NTLM WWW authentication. If I try to access some of the URLs using Firefox, i get an 401 Unauthorized + login dlg. Internet Exploder performs NTLM auth in the background and grants access. It seems that the Java URLConnection (or URL) class does the same, because I am getting no 401. Is there a way to disable implicit NTLM authentication in Java? This is a bad pitfall for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Java Network Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html) is the best resource. Setting the `http.auth.preference="basic"` should get you what you want. Assuming you don't need digest or something else. I'm not sure if you can go beyond that to disable NTLM.

Another thing to consider is other Java HTTP client implementations, like Apache's or Google's.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your *very* quick reply. I just tested the setting - unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. However, thank you very much! I think I will need to replace URLConnection with the HttpClient from Apache -.- . I wanted to get around this, because the current solution is so nicely quick and dirty :) Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will help, but I've been stumped by the opposite.

I *wanted* NTLM auth to take place, so on my local machine I use a free app called CNTLM.  It's a local proxy server that will forward (and NT auth) incoming requests.  Good for apps that can't use NTLM proxies.

I'm sorry, I know this isn't answering your question, but maybe it proves helpful to someone out there! :)

Comment: Hey, I use Windows 7 here with JRE 1.6.0.22 and NTLM works (unfortunately) like a charm. You may try to use my code snipped above... maybe it saves you some trouble!

Comment: I'm here with a third experience to add. I'm on Mac OS X and Java does appear to be replying using NTLM, but the server rejects the response and then offers NTLM and Basic as alternatives, which of course causes an infinite loop. Gotta love Microsoft's adherence to web standards. :(